# SchemaSpy without any direct database connection

Tags: database-schema, offline, schemaspy

I want to use SchemaSpy, but I my database is used heavily 24/7 and the DBA won't give me access, even readonly.  However, i can give the DBA some commands and he can run them and give me the results.

Is it possible for SchemaSpy to run offline mode? In other words, Can I give it a dump of all the "CREATE TABLE, CREATE INDEX" and a list of all the sizes of the tables, and then it can generate the report?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, The best thing about schemaspy is that it automatically runs and collects all the objects and in the case of the tables performed a count.

In your specific case you can use a work around as follows.

Ask your DBA for a dump or even the empty bank creation script, just the structures. And direct schemaspy to that bank that simulates your production.

By the way I have created a docker image that uses schamespy to document all the bases of a server.

https://github.com/krismorte/database-diagrams